# biblatex: When is the content of a field available

Tags: biblatex

I am currently adding the possibility to my style `biblatex-fiwi` to add an alternative title to films. This is in itself is not complicated. But I also want a mechanism which handles different scripts. The idea is that, depending on the script, a bibmacro will be created which can later be defined to load a specific supports which supports the needed script.

I added the two fields `alternatetitle` and `alternatetitlescript`. For this, the following lines must be added to a .dbx-File, for example `biblatex-dm.cfg`:

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{alternatetitle}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{alternatetitlescript}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[movie,misc,video]{alternatetitle, alternatetitlescript}
```

The following MWE example is a bit complicated:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @movie{themovie,
        Address = {USA},
        Alternatetitle = {Аэлита},  
        Alternatetitlescript = {cyrillic},  
        Director = {Mad, Max},
        Title = {The Title},
        Year = {1996}}
\end{filecontents} 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=fiwi]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewbibmacro*{filmtitle}{\iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {\printtext{\printfield[film]{title}}}
  {\printfield[film]{maintitle}\newunit}% 
\iffieldundef{alternatetitle}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:cite-alternatetitle}} 
\iffieldundef{subtitle}%
  {}% 
  {\setunit{}% 
\printtext{\addspace\printfield{subtitle}}}%
\iffieldundef{volume}% 
  {}% 
  {\printfield[season]{volume}}%
\iffieldundef{number}% 
  {}%
  {\addcomma\addspace\printfield[episode]{number}}%
\iffieldundef{maintitle}% 
  {}%
  {\addcolon\addspace\printfield[film]{title}}% 
\ifpunctmark{!}{\unspace.\newunit}{\adddot}}%

\newbibmacro*{bbx:cite-alternatetitle}{
\iffieldundef{alternatetitlescript}
  {\addslash\printfield{alternatetitle}}
  {\addslash\ifbibmacroundef{altscript:\strfield{alternatetitlescript}-font}
  {\textsc{\thefield{alternatetitle}}}{\usebibmacro{altscript:\strfield{alternatetitlescript}-font}%
    {\thefield{alternatetitle}}} }}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newbibmacro*{altscript:cyrillic-font}[1]{\newfontfamily\cyrfont[Extension = .ttf,]{Linux Libertine}{\cyrfont{\textsc{#1}}}} 

\begin{document} 
\citefilm{themovie} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The idea is that a macro called `altscript:<alternatetitlescript>-font`is created which can the be defined in the document. The problem is that the content of `alternatetitlescript`is not resolved. This is even more strange, as the test whether `alternatetitlescript`is empty or not, actually works. But later when it should be become part of the macro name, the content `alternatetitlescript`seems not available.

Comment: You will want to use the starred version of `\usebibmacro`: `\usebibmacro*{altscript:\strfield{alternatetitlescript}-font}{\thefield{alternatetitle}}`, the starred version does not try to sanitise the name before use, which is what you need here.

Comment: That was easy, thanks! Please turn this into a proper answer.

Comment: I feel that what you want should be doable more elegantly without the need for low-level `\the...` commands, but I have no idea how. (Though I believe `\textsc{\thefield{alternatetitle}}` could *probably* be `\printfield{alternatetitle}` + an appropriate `\DeclareFieldFormat`. Are you sure all those `\iffieldundefs` are needed? Normally the punctuation tracker and the correct commands `\setunit`/`\setunit*`/`\printunit`/`\printunit*` should make sure you don't get into trouble because of missing fields.)

Comment: I will look into that. I started out with a `DeclareFieldFormat` but this did not work with indexing.

Comment: Indexing obeys `\DeclareIndexFieldFormat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unstarred version of `\usebibmacro` sanitises the macro name with a `\detokenize`. Since we want the `\strfield{alternatetitlescript}` to be expanded, we need to work around that. The starred version `\usebibmacro*` does not do any sanitising on the macro name and so

```
\usebibmacro*{altscript:\strfield{alternatetitlescript}-font}{\thefield{alterna‌​tetitle}}
```

works as expected.